# Dropwizard and EJB integration

Tags: glassfish, ejb, dropwizard

G'Day mates,

I want to use Dropwizard to access my business logic which is encapsulated in EJB layer hosted on Glassfish.

From Dropwizard website, Dropwizard uses Jetty as a built-in application server. Which as far as I know is not EJB compatible.

How can I build a webservice layer that can consume my business layer and at the same time I can utilize the run any where .jar services?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Consuming an EJB web service does not require to use EJB. Its just SOAP over HTTP, so you can do it with a simple HTTP client application.

Normally you would generate proxy code from the wsdl to use with JAVA, check out apache cxf or the jaxws-maven-plugin.

Comment: It's not an EJB web service. It is normal EJB which encapsulate business layer.

Normally you use (@)EJB annotation to inject a bean and use it.

So how can I use (@)EJB in Dropwizard? By default this is not supported

Comment: No, you cant use @EJB. But you can use a remote ejb client api, lookup the service and call its methods. Thats standard remoting and will also work in dw.